# Angular JS display and edit model in textarea

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, object

I would like to be able to edit and display complex model in a `<textarea>` element. Here's the HTML piece for generating model's fields dynamically from JSON response:

```
<p>parent uuid*: </p>
<input ng-model="parentUuid" capitalize type="text" placeholder="String"
    class="form-control" style="width:200px; display: inline-block;"/> <br/>
<p>resource*:</p>
<select ng-model="childResource" ng-change="loadResourceFields(childResource)" 
    class="form-control" style="width:300px; display: inline-block;">
    <option ng-repeat="childResource in restResources">{{childResource}}</option>
</select>
<div ng-repeat="field in childFields">
    <div ng-show={{!field.isEnum}}>
        <p ng-show={{field.isRequired}}>{{field.name}}*: </p>
        <p ng-show={{!field.isRequired}}>{{field.name}}: </p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="createChildResource[field.name]"
            class="form-control" style="width:200px; display: inline-block;" placeholder="{{parseClassName(field.type)}}">
    </div>
    <div ng-show={{field.isEnum}}>
        <p ng-show={{field.isRequired}}>{{field.name}}*: </p>
        <p ng-show={{!field.isRequired}}>{{field.name}}: </p>
        <select ng-model="createChildResource[field.name]" class="form-control" style="width:auto; display: inline-block;">
            <option></option>
            <option ng-repeat="enumValue in field.enumValues" label={{enumValue.name}}>{{enumValue.ordinal}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="preview">
    <p>Preview: </p>
    <textarea style="height:350px; width:550px; overflow:scroll;">{{createChildResource | json}}</textarea >
</div>
```

The output is the following:

[image]

But if I try to add a `ngModel` to a textarea element to be able to edit this values in place like this:

```
<div class="preview">
    <p>Preview: </p>
    <textarea ng-model="createChildResource" style="height:350px; width:550px; overflow:scroll;">{{createChildResource | json}}</textarea>
</div>
```

then the output is the following:

[image]

In both cases I can't edit my model in a textarea element.

How can this be achieved? I'd like to be able to display and edit my model inplace like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/32/) with a slight difference: `editable-textarea="user.description"` should be `editable-textarea="user"`.

Comment: `createChildResource` is an object and thus is shown as an object inside the textarea. Try converting the object to a string - `JSON.stringify()` perhaps and you should see the contents.

Comment: Yes, now I am able to see the content of an object but still I can't change it.

Comment: You mean the change is not reflected in the controller or other areas of the view or the textarea is disabled and you can't edit the contents?

Comment: The view is ok, but If I try to change anything inside textarea - object fields just don't update.

Comment: Sorry - I did not put it correctly. The object fields do not update inside the textarea or somewhere else?

Comment: Textarea is editable and it seems ok. Object fields do not update in their own input fields inside the form.

Comment: Possibly I am using JSON.stringify() in a wrong place. Where is it supposed to be used? I can't just convert my whole model..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally understand what you are trying to achieve. On the left you have a bunch of inputs and on the right (bottom), you have a textarea that arranges the inputs as properties of one object and displays them formatted as an object.

Your requirements is to allow user to edit the property values in the textarea and thus update the corresponding property value in the input.

First, as commented, convert the object to a string and then show it inside the textarea.

Next, since you need to react and update the input fields when the textarea is updated, you need to `watch` the value of the textarea and update the original object (the one that was converted to string).

Using an example here since your code is too complex to understand, let us say that you have the object `containerObject` as follows:

```
$scope.containerObject = {
    property_1: "Hello",
    property_2: "World"
};
```

Your inputs then make use of these properties:

```
<input ng-model="containerObject.property_1">

<input ng-model="containerObject.property_2">
```

Now, you wish to display this inside your textarea - you will first convert the object to string and display it as follows:

```
$scope.getObjectAsText = function () {
    $scope.textAreaModel = JSON.stringify($scope.containerObject);
};
```

And your textarea markup will look like:

```
<textarea ng-model="textAreaModel"></textarea>
```

Each time the value in the input textboxes change, the textarea also gets updated.

Now, for the other way around. When you change the textarea, to have the input textboxes get updated, you need to watch the string model (and NOT the object model):

```
$scope.$watch('textAreaModel', function () {
    try {
        $scope.containerObject = JSON.parse($scope.textAreaModel);
    } catch(exp) {
        //Exception handler
    };
});
```

You need to have the `try...catch` exception handler block because the user may accidentally change the contents such that on converting back to object, the result is not a suitable object (invalid property or invalid syntax).

As long as only the property value is changed, the input values will get updated correctly.

Comment: Yes, you understood target and requirments correctly. It seems to me that this solution will work just fine. Anyway, thank you for your big contribution. It cleared some issues. Your answer is 100% useful. I will inform you as soon as I get some results. Thx :)

Comment: Where am I supposed to use function getObjectAsText()?

Comment: I guess it should be an ng-change="getObjectAsText()" on every input?

Comment: Great, It helped me :) But there's still one issue left: the String in textarea is ugly formatted comparing to the one that was before. Any thoughts how this can be handled? I'll create a separate question if you can help me with this too. This question is solved. Thank you very much :)

Comment: My bad - I initially intended to use `getObjectAsText()` as the model in the view but then changed my mind to use `textAreaAsModel` instead. You can use it in the `ng-change` directive or you can set up another `$scope.$watch()` on the object this time and call `getObjectAsText()` to update the textarea content each time the input changes.

Comment: Please do create a new question for formatting of text inside textarea

Comment: Please, see this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785552/angularjs-format-json-string-output

Answer (score 4):

You can also wrap it into directive like below, or check the [jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/1195/)

**Html**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='userCtrl' >
    <textarea obj-edit obj="user" rows='10'></textarea>
    <p ng-bind='user.name'></p>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('userCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user= {name: 'ron', ocupation: 'coder'};
});
app.directive('objEdit', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            obj:'=obj'
        }, 
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.text(JSON.stringify(scope.obj, undefined, 2));
            element.change(function(e) {
                console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.obj = JSON.parse(e.currentTarget.value);
                });
                console.log(scope.obj);
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Nice Ron. I went ahead and took it an extra step by using `$parsers` and `$formatters` in the standard `ngModel` [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bsnzt)

Answer (score 3):

[Ron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22784868/4320665) is great.
Here is code that uses `ngModel` validation

**HTML**

```
<form name="text">
   <textarea obj-edit ng-model="ctrl.json" name="json" rows="25" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 300 }"></textarea>
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-show="text.json.$error.json">
        Error input
   </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
app.directive('objEdit', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$formatters.push(function formatter(value) {
            return JSON.stringify(value, undefined, 2);
        });
        ctrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
            try {
                var result = JSON.parse(value);
                ctrl.$setValidity('json', true);
                return result;
            } catch (e) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('json', false);
                return undefined;
            }
        });

    }
}});
```