# AngularJS format JSON string output

Tags: javascript, json, string, angularjs, formatting

I have an AngularJS application, which collects data from input, transforms a model into a string using `JSON.stringify()` and lets a user edit this model in such a way that input fields get updated if the `<textarea>` element is updated and vice versa. Some kind of two-way binding :)

The problem is that the String itself looks ugly and I would like to format it so it looks like this:

[image]

And not like it looks now:

[image]

Any ideas how this can be accomplished? If you need some additional info - don't hesitate asking. Every answer is highly appreciated and answered immediately.

Thank you.

P.S. I guess this should be some kind of directive or a custom filter. Data itself SHOULD NOT be changed, only the output.

Comment: Can you try this - In the textarea, press enter and format the resultant string as desired. Then in your `$watch` (based on the answer to previous question) over the textarea model, can you do a `console.log()` and see what value you get in the string for the enter key - I think it's "/n"

Comment: Based on this, I can suggest how you can format the text

Comment: {"anchorPosition":"1",
"difficulty":"1",
"includeInSequence":"1",
"questionCount":"1"}

Comment: Basically nothing changed after String got formated.

Comment: See answers below - do they help?

Comment: Yup, Lukasz's answer helped to solve the problem. Thank you too ;)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use an optional parameter of `JSON.stringify()`

> `JSON.stringify(value[, replacer [, space]])`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - *value* The value to convert to a JSON string.
> - *replacer* If a function,
>     transforms values and properties encountered while stringifying; if an
>     array, specifies the set of properties included in objects in the
>     final string. A detailed description of the replacer function is
>     provided in the javaScript guide article Using native JSON.
> - *space*
>     Causes the resulting string to be pretty-printed.

For example:

```
JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2,c:{d:3, e:4}},null,"    ")
```

will give you following result:

```
"{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": {
        "d": 3,
        "e": 4
    }
}"
```

Comment: note that this preserves the `$$hashKey` property angular uses for internal model tracking

Comment: You can also do `JSON.stringify(object, null, 2)` where 2 is the number of white space characters.

Comment: @ Lukasz, Can I avoid the $$Hashkey?

Answer (score 439):

Angular has a built-in `filter` for showing `JSON`

```
<pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
```

Note the use of the `pre`-tag to conserve whitespace and linebreaks

Demo:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {

      $scope.data = {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: {
          d: "3"
        },
      };

    }
  ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.15" data-semver="1.2.15" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
  </body>

</html>
```

There's also an `angular.toJson` method, but I haven't played around with that ([Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson))

Comment: Yes, I know this already. But I can't make this filter because the textarea itself is a model.

Comment: This is so simple, yet so useful :D

Comment: @ra170 Be so kind to read the whole question carefully, not just the heading. I was asking for a slightly different thing than a simple json filter.

Comment: Note that your `<pre>` tag shouldn't have `white-space` property set to `normal` or `no-wrap`. Otherwise, your JSON wouldn't be indented as you want.

Comment: I was having problems but I was doing without <pre>.... I saw this answer and I fixed .... thanks!!

Comment: this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Well, this may not anser the OP question, but it answers the question for the majority of the people that ended up here when searching for it... ;)

Answer (score 23):

If you are looking to render JSON as HTML and it can be collapsed/opened, you can use this directive that I just made to render it nicely:

https://github.com/mohsen1/json-formatter/

[image]

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the [angular `json` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json) already mentioned, there is also the [angular `toJson()` function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson).

```
angular.toJson(obj, pretty);
```

The second param of this function lets you switch on pretty printing and set the number of spaces to use.

> If set to true, the JSON output will contain newlines and whitespace. If set to an integer, the JSON output will contain that many spaces per indentation.
>
> (default: 2)

Comment: my page is blocked when i give him a array of 1000 objects

Comment: Youvariable = angular.toJson ...., as you wrote, it looks like the result in pretty

Answer (score 6):

I guess you want to use  to edit the json text.
Then you can use ivarni's way:

```
{{data | json}}
```

and add an adition attribute to make

```
 editable
```

`<pre contenteditable="true">{{data | json}}</pre>`

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to format the JSON and also do some syntax highlighting, you can use the `ng-prettyjson` directive. [See the npm package.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-prettyjson)

Here is how to use it: `<pre pretty-json="jsonObject"></pre>`