# Angular: JSON filter in textarea produces a lot of slashes

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, coffeescript

I have a problem, I have an object which needs to be editable via a textarea.
The object is binded via `ng-model` with the textarea. Because it is JSON it is handy to have it parsed down to a nice style, so I used the json filter build in to Angular. But this renders the JSON in the textarea with a lot of backslashes. They seem to be at the place where a linebreak should be.

The rendered output in a textarea vs a div:
[image: output]

I would like the JSON be renderd in the textarea the same as in the div.

HTML:

```
<div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
   <textarea id="formState" ng-model="textAreaState"></textarea>
   <pre>{{textAreaState | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.$watch 'formState', ((val) ->
    $scope.textAreaState = $filter('json')(angular.toJson(angular.copy ($builder.formState)))
    return
), true
```

So my question: How do I get the textarea formatted the same way as the div?

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785552/angularjs-format-json-string-output

Comment: I found my error,  
the filter filtered to JSON, but I already did `angular.toJson`. So I removed `angular.toJson` and it worked fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove `angular.toJson()` because the value is already in json-format!