# $uib-modal error on open and close

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am having problems opening up a simple modal popup.

I am using uib-bootstrap 14.3, angular.js 1.4.7, bootstrap 3.3.5.

I followed the documentation and examples I have found online and even with a blank modal template, not referencing item inside of template, I get same errors. Now some of my objects I am passing into the modal popup have long JSON date formatted DateTime members.

In my HTML I have a details button inside of a table with ng-repeat on a database log records tracked by index:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg', $index)">Details <i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

In the controller that is where the above button is scoped in calls the modal instance as such:

```
$scope.open = function (size, $index) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'Modal.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            item: function () {
                return $scope.$storage.items[$index];
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    });
 };
```

the Modal Controller:

```
angular.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, item) {
     $scope.item = item;

     $scope.selected = {
         item: $scope.item
     };

     $scope.ok = function () {
         $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
     };

     $scope.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
     };
});
```

The Modal template:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Item</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>{{item}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
             <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The error I see when I click on the button and the modal should appear losing focus on background:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: parseDateFilterProvider <- parseDateFilter  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=parseDateFilterProvider%20%3C-%20parseDateFilter

at angular.js?v=122215174314:68
at angular.js?v=122215174314:4289
at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js?v=122215174314:4437)
at angular.js?v=122215174314:4294
at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js?v=122215174314:4437)
at angular.js?v=122215174314:18229
at isStateless (angular.js?v=122215174314:13130)
at findConstantAndWatchExpressions (angular.js?v=122215174314:13187)
at angular.js?v=122215174314:13190
at forEach (angular.js?v=122215174314:336)
```

When I try to hit esc button on my keyboard I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined

at Function.extend.removeClass (angular.js?v=122215174314:3568)
at m (angular-animate.js:1141)
at F (angular-animate.js:1198)
at angular-animate.js:889
at afterAnimating (ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js?v=122215174314:3834)
at processQueue (angular.js?v=122215174314:14745)
at angular.js?v=122215174314:14761
at Scope.$eval (angular.js?v=122215174314:15989)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js?v=122215174314:15800)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js?v=122215174314:16097)
```

The item variable is referencing this object 3 integers, 1 string, and 1 datetime object from asp.net backend.

The weird part is that even if I do not have anything with a date being referenced I still see the date parse provider error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS format JSON string output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785552/angularjs-format-json-string-output)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in the modal. Put in your plunk json object with server side data that throws exception and check the difference. 
I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785552/angularjs-format-json-string-output) will be useful for you. The main idea is that you have to convert you json dates to js Date or use angular built-in json filter

```
{{item | json}}
```

Comment: Okay so crazy thing is that I got it working in Plunker but not in my project.  I have tried simplifying it with similar code as my Plunker example.  However, I still see a date parse error.  [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/N2cy5sWejXGjJeXWOmzF)

Comment: In your plunk you printed constant string on the modal and it`s ok, but in the app you try to print out json object with date and got error, you have to assign same value to the item in plunk that thrown a error in application. Also, if it confused you, it is better to delete modal code, its ok, you can use it later, but now left just a variable with server side json data and try print out it and understand difference.