# how to access this complex json object with angular js?

Tags: angularjs, json, object

```
$scope.data = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "success",
    "result": {
        "data2": [
            {
                "viewTitle": "one",
                "viewType": 1,
                "viewData": "{\"data3\":{\"_id\":\"one\"," +
                "\"channelId\":\"0\",\"channelName\":\"animals\"," +
                "\"rate\":3.5,\"visited\":21,\"meta\":{\"currency\":\"t\"" +
                ",\"size\":\"5 mb\",\"updatedAt\":\"2 2 2016\"" +
                ",\"createdAt\":\"2 2 2016\",\"duration\":\"3 minutes \"}" +
                ",\"thumbnail\":\"127.0.0.1\"" +
                ",\"banner\":\"127.0.0.1\"" +
                ",\"trailerUrl\":\"\",\"url\":\"127.0.0.1\"" +
                ",\"desc\":\"my informations \"" +
                ",\"title\":\"my videos number 4\",\"packages\"" +
                ":[{\"_id\":\"1\",\"price\":500" +
                ",\"type\":\"purchase\"}],\"packageId\":\"2\"" +
                ",\"packagePrice\":500,\"userFavorite\":0,\"userRate\":0,\"locked\":1}}"
            }
        ]
    }
};`
```

I try to access for example chanelName or size please help to resolve.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson Make the Json  string in `result.data2.viewData` an object, and treat it as any other object in your js code.

Answer (score 0):

first, turn the JSON string into an object via `JSON.parse();` 
`var data = JSON.parse();
//data is now the result of JSON.parse`
 
and then access the property you want to use in `$scope.data`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a CodePen for your Problem: 
http://codepen.io/JohannesFerner/pen/PNmmBd/

You have `JSON.parse(<escaped JSON property>)` or `angular.fromJson(<escaped JSON property>)` (see the comment above) your escaped JSON.

---

Without further knowledge of your backend I would suggest that you do not deliver escaped JSON to the client.

Answer (score 0):

First level objects can be accessed like this.

```
person.result.data2[0].viewTitle
```

JSON.parse is the easiest way here to disassemble the complex object. I have given my example below

http://jsfiddle.net/MisterFantastic/u8bhc1ds/1/

```
JSON.parse(person.result.data2[0].viewData)
```

For complex objects please refer this link.
[AngularJS format JSON string output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785552/angularjs-format-json-string-output)