# Angular JS - display and edit model in textarea AND update when model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textarea, angular-ngmodel

I just came from this post:

[Angular JS display and edit model in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783268/angular-js-display-and-edit-model-in-textarea)

It was very helpful in what I'm trying to achieve, however I need to take it a step further and make the textarea update when model values change. I'm working with last [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bsnzt) by @JustMaier from the above post. I think I need to add a `$watch` but not sure how/where exactly.. Appreciate your help on this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `watch` your `model` value in the `directive` and trigger the `formatters` on change:

```
scope.$watch(function() {
    return ngModel.$modelValue;
}, function(modelValue) {
    // trigger the formatters
    ngModel.$modelValue = '';
}, true);
```

### [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPaOgm)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. Its actaully documeented ngModel doesnt watch for deep changes and so doesnt zpdate view when model change deeply:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

So you need to add ngModel value to the directive scope in order to use `$watch` on it:

```
scope:{'ngModel':'='}
```

and then add watch that will update view value into directive link function:

```
scope.$watch ('ngModel', function (newval) { 
  ngModel.$viewValue = toJson(newval);
  ngModel.$render();
}, true);
```

See demo:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbWamy